Has a theory in science ever gone against Occam’s razor?
Occam’s razor, often more specifically rephrased as the principle of parsimony, states,

However, a standard of formulation of the principle of parsimony—one that seems to be reasonably close to the sort of principle that Ockham himself probably would have endorsed—is as the maxim “entities are not to be multiplied beyond necessity”

On the face of it, many may point out the existence of complex theories as evidence that Occam’s razor has been nullified. But given the above principle, the principle does not say that the simplest explanation is always true. Rather, it says that entities are not to be multiplied beyond necessity. It may be the case that hypothesis A may be simpler than hypothesis B but hypothesis B is necessary to explain all relevant data, thus the additional postulates of B may be necessary.
The question, then, is: has there been a case where multiple theories explained or predicted the same set of data, and the more complex theory ended up, for newly discovered reasons, being true?
———————-
Note: I realize that this question may seem a little loaded. Suppose you have a simpler theory A and a more complex theory B that explain all known data. If one then discovers additional data that only theory B can explain but not theory A, and then one prefers theory B, then it could be still argued that we are not going against the razor, since it only applies if each theory explains everything well. I am personally not sure how to interpret this philosophically.

@MauroALLEGRANZA how do you know that? And how do you know that they’re not using it unconsciously? For example, there are tons of people who have never heard of the term induction yet use it in practice since our brains are wired for pattern matching out of habit. How do you know the same is not being done in preferring simpler hypotheses? One could even argue that induction itself is following Occam’s razor since the assumption of a law/pattern being generalized from particular instances is simpler than not.

@MauroALLEGRANZA That is incorrect. Occam's razor is foundational to doing science. Heck, Occam’s razor is foundational to just navigating the world generally (although we may not label it as such). If you see a single row of footprints on the beach, you assume it was made by 1 person (and you'd be correct almost all of the time). You don't assume it was made by 100 people all stepping in one another's tracks (unless you have some evidence that suggests this).

Is heliocentrism replacing géocentrisme an example answer. The question makes this so unclear that I feel like voting to close for lack of clarity

Though it can also be close as duplicate of https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/what-is-an-event-that-was-a-counterexample-to-occams-razor. Also see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/26/was-occam-s-razor-ever-wrong, causing this to maybe be the wrong site for the question. So many close reasons...

@NotThatGuy Please don't lose the focus: "Entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem." Occam's razor prompts to not introduce additional concepts(!) when the same result can be obtained by less concepts. An example from science: Do not reason about the properties of an aether when electrodynamics operates fine without this concept. - Of course you can generalize the principle: Avoid sophisticated hypotheses when a simple hypothesis explains the same phenomenon.

I believe @MauroALLEGRANZA is saying that when judging a scientific theory for merit, Occams Razor is the last method used not the first and many times Occams Razor is not required.

@IdiosyncraticSoul it is unconsciously required in the sense that scientists don’t even bother investigating hypotheses that are unfalsifiable for example. But unfalsifiable hypotheses are usually also more complex, such as the hypotheses that invisible pixies are controlling my fingers in such a way that they still obey scientific laws

@Syed My only consistent use of Occams Razor is when I shop. The "best" product between two identical products is the one that costs less.

@IdiosyncraticSoul yes, and Occam’s razor isn’t meant to distinguish between hypotheses that don’t explain the same thing :)

Furthermore, when I shop I don't automatically buy the cheapest product. Im buying a product for a purpose and i want the least expendive product that meets my requirements. I only use Occams Razor to distinguish between two identical products.

Finally, as time goes on products become obsolete and are replaced with products that meet the requirements of the time. Whether this is a failure of Occams Razor is based on your definition of failure.

My definition of Occams Razor failure is this:
I have two products built by different manufacturers Both identically meet my requirements for the task but one is cheaper so I buy it.
It fails after two days because even though the product met my performance requirements. Once I opened the box I could see the manufacturing quality and material quality was low (information that was not available at the time of purchase since the boxes were opaque and sealed).
How has Occams Razor failed? I used Occams with incomplete information.

@Syed What is in the background of all science is the knowledge that our understanding of the universe is incomplete. So it's very easy for Occams Razor to fail.

@IdiosyncraticSoul you haven’t given an example of a failure of Occam’s razor apart from analogies that don’t neatly fit into it

Listen.. Occam's Razor doesn't dictate that the simplest explanation is always true, but rather that we shouldn't add unnecessary complexity. If a more complex theory is required to explain all the data, then that complexity is justified, why not..
So yeah, there were cases where a more complex theory proved more accurate than a simpler one, even when both initially explained the available data.
For example...
The Ptolemaic vs. Copernican models of the solar system
Initially, both models could predict the observed motions of planets. The Ptolemaic model, with Earth at the center, was arguably simpler in its basic premise. However, to accurately predict planetary positions, it required increasingly complex additions of epicycles (circles within circles). The Copernican model, with the Sun at the center, was conceptually more complex but gave a simpler and more accurate explanation as more precise observations became available. So you see - initial simplicity can hide underlying complexity, and a more fundamentally sound, though more complex theory can prevail!
The discovery of the neutrino
Beta decay, a type of radioactive decay, initially kinda violated the law of conservation of energy. A simpler explanation would have been to modify or discard the conservation law. But then Pauli proposed the existence of a new particle – the neutrino – which carried away the missing energy. This added a new entity, making the theory more complex. Experiments later confirmed the neutrino's existence, it illustrates that preserving fundamental principles (like conservation laws) can sometimes justify adding complexity.
So you're right, the situation where a simpler theory is later superseded by a more complex one due to new data doesn't necessarily violate Occam's Razor. The razor applies when both theories explain the current data equally well. Once new data emerges that only the more complex theory can explain, the simpler theory is no longer adequate, and the added complexity of the other theory becomes "necessary."

You described it correctly.

+1 great answer :-)

+1 The examples also illustrate that "Occam's razor" is never used in actual science to select among candidate explanations because it's an ambiguous rule. It's possible to present the same theoretical development either as "increasing complexity" and as "increasing simplicity".

As I understand it, Occam's razor might work on the motion of planets like this...
A: The planets move in circular orbits.
B: The planets move in circular orbits on crystal spheres.
Unless we have some kind of evidence, the 'crystal spheres' bit contributes nothing. We can simplify the description by leaving it out. Occam's razor does not judge between two competing statements; it is used only when one statement effectively contains the other.

@mudskipper The answer shows how Occam's razor is used in actual science. I'm not sure how you ended up with the exact opposite conclusion.

@NotThatGuy - Isn't that clear from my comment? :) Occam's razor can be turned any which way you want to turn it. The Ptolemaic system was simpler initially -- what is simpler than assuming the earth stands still, in the middle: this is everyday experience -- and when it was becoming pretty complicated it was still extremely accurate. It's only gradually that we learned to accept heliocentrism as "simpler". I'm not denying that some esthetic sense doesn't play a role for scientists, I'm merely denying that anyone ever actually "applied Occam's razor". It's a philosophical fiction imo.

So, imo "simpler" is (1) never unambiguous, and (2) it's applied mostly retroactively (in popular accounts of science, not in actual scientific practice, apart as vague sense of esthetics), and (3) accuracy and explanatory power (relations to other theories and experiments) matter more (or at least as much).

@mudskipper (1) If you conceive of a different interpretation of Occam's razor, that doesn't mean the way it's used in science is ambiguous. You're imagining a problem where none exists in practice. (2) You basically seem to be saying that our retroactive analysis of the history of science is retroactive, therefore Occam's razor is only used retroactively. That doesn't follow. We picked the models that we did at the time because they avoided unnecessary complexity (i.e. Occam's razor). (3) Accuracy and explanatory power is part of determining which complexity is needed (for Occam's razor).

Occam's razor is used in science as a practical tool for sorting which models to examine first as easy as to test and, arguably, most elegant. It does not select which model we continue with; that is done on the basis of the models ability to explain and predict reality.

@keshlam an infinite number of models can explain and predict reality, believe it or not. You just unconsciously disregard the more complex models using Occam’s razor without realizing it ;) if you disagree, please tell me why you disregard or even consider unlikely the hypothesis that invisible pixies are controlling the universe through scientific laws.

I don't see a conflict between that and what I said. Occam's razor is a tool for deciding which models we want to explore first. When they fail, if they fail, we proceed to more complex models. If both complex and simple models are equally effective, there is no reason to prefer the more complex ones. The pixies model is not effective at making predictions, hence it is not favored.

@keshlam but the task of which hypotheses to choose to investigate has nothing to do with Occam’s razor even though it may indeed be pragmatic to focus on simpler hypotheses first. The razor only comes in with regards to the second part of your comment: picking the simpler hypothesis if the complex hypothesis does the same job

If they both do the job, of course humans are going to prefer the simpler solution. Why work harder than you have to? Unless you think that there is something that the simpler model doesn't capture, or unless you think you can simplify things by temporarily making them more complicated, or unless you just plan have an emotional reason for preferring the more complicated solution, most humans do prefer simplicity. You aren't required to. The razor is a tool; there are other tools; pick the one that suits the way you want to work.

Remember, we aren't "choosing" hypotheses on anything but a provisional basis. Let a million flowers bloom, try to breed the ones you find prettiest, if you don't like the results go back and try some of the others. Or try something else entirely. That isn't even metaphysics; it's pure practicality. Occam's razor is just a pithy summary of that.

@keshlam again, you are merely asserting that this is all just practicality, over and over again. There are plenty of arguments philosophers have come up with that assign a truth finding role to simplicity. Of course, parsimony doesn’t imply truth completely, but neither is it “pure” practicality

@syed: we agree that we disagree. Presuming that you do disagree, since otherwise I'm not sure what you are challenging.


The question, then, is: has there been a case where multiple theories explained or predicted the same set of data, and the more complex theory ended up, for newly discovered reasons, being true?

This could be said for any new successful theory proposed, where there is a period of time before sufficient data is collected to demonstrate the greater explanatory power of the new theory. Prior to the collection of new data, the existing data could be equally explained by the prior accepted theory and the new theory, so initially Occam's Razor would favor the prior theory. However, this wouldn’t prevent the proponent of the new theory from maintaining faith or hope in their theory, contra Occam’s Razor.
One notable example is the Eddington experiment:

The Eddington experiment was an observational test of general relativity, organised by the British astronomers Frank Watson Dyson and Arthur Stanley Eddington in 1919. The observations were of the total solar eclipse of 29 May 1919 and were carried out by two expeditions, one to the West African island of Príncipe, and the other to the Brazilian town of Sobral. The aim of the expeditions was to measure the gravitational deflection of starlight passing near the Sun.[1] The value of this deflection had been predicted by Albert Einstein in a 1911 paper; however, this initial prediction turned out not to be correct because it was based on an incomplete theory of general relativity. Einstein later improved his prediction after finalizing his theory in 1915 and obtaining the solution to his equations by Karl Schwarzschild. Following the return of the expeditions, the results were presented by Eddington to the Royal Society of London[2] and, after some deliberation, were accepted. Widespread newspaper coverage of the results led to worldwide fame for Einstein and his theories.

One could argue that, technically, Einstein was acting against Occam's Razor by placing hope in his new theory before sufficient evidence had been gathered to confirm it.

Your question is worded broadly enough so as to include all exact sciences including mathematics.  If this was your intention, it is worth noticing that such "parsimony" is far from being the case in the foundations of mathematics.  First, the axioms of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF) perhaps seem simple to a set-theorist, but they "multiply entities beyond necessity" to such an extent that a whole field of mathematics was created in part so as to combat ZF.  Furthermore, the set-theoretic assumption V=L perhaps goes in the direction of parsimony you mentioned, but it is generally rejected by professional set theorists in favor of pletudinous theories allowing a wild proliferation of large cardinals.
In mathematics one certainly "gets proof" but one does not get proof as to which foundational system is preferable. Here one have to guess just as much as in the other exact sciences.

Unfortunately, I am not a mathematician, so I cannot comment on this. However, when talking about science, we are not generally talking about mathematics even if scientific theories can be formulated by math as far as I know, since the field of mathematics is generally regarded as not empirical.

Occam's razor seems to be applicable to all sorts of theories that are not empirical (even if you assume that math is not, which is debatable), such as hylomorphism and other religious doctrines.

the field of mathematics seems a little tricky to me since everything is either implied by the axioms of math or not, and thus any mathematical proofs seem to merely be a process of discovering which implications occur and which don’t. This then begs the question of whether a “mathematical explanation” really makes sense when it’s really just a reformulation. Nevertheless, as mentioned, I am not a mathematician, so take my opinion with a grain of salt! @Mikhail Katz

The issue is which axioms to choose as a starting point.  Today there is a variety of foundational systems to pick from: set theory, category theory, etc.  Even within set theory there are various possibilities and not just one.

In mathematics, the axioms themselves do not have to be proven; here the question is pointless. The same applies to logic. In philosophy, it is different, since you have to justify the principles yourself.

No, it is not pointless.  The choice of the axioms is a nontrivial issue that has much to do with Occam's razor in fact.  @tenebris

It doesn't matter which axioms you choose, the proof is always valid as long as the chosen axioms are valid. There are no invalid conclusions from the axioms because the axioms themselves are assumed to be true and the conclusion is always valid. This has more to do with aesthetics, but nothing in the same sense as in empirical science, where you never know for sure whether a hypothesis is correct.

There is much debate in among mathematicians interested in the philosophy of mathematics around the issue of which foundational framework is preferable.  There are many publications in this area.  You are perhaps personally not interested in this particular area, but nonetheless it exists.  @tenebris

@Katz You first have to know exactly what mathematics is. Have you read Kant? He explains it in detail. If so, then I can work it out in more detail, using Kantian terms. What I wrote above is correct, but without knowing Kant it might not be understandable. I have written detailed works on the deduction of mathematics and logic.

My point is not that there is no debate, but that the razor is absolutely necessary in empirical science because you don't get any proof. Mathematics, like logic and philosophy, has real proof, which you don't get in empirical science. So you always have to guess.

@tenebris, I agree that in mathematics you "get proof".  However, you don't get proof as to which foundational system is preferable.  Here you have to guess just as in the other exact sciences.

I agree here with you.

@MikhailKatz We don't just "guess" which foundational system is preferable in maths. A system is chosen based on what's useful for some purpose or what most accurately reflects real-world data, and what reliably produces accurate predictions. A system with no practical uses isn't "wrong", it just isn't useful. The axioms themselves are not multiplied beyond necessity (Occam's razor) - we try to establish the absolute minimal set of axioms needed, and avoid more intricate axioms where simpler ones would do.

Large cardinals are introduced for fixing the landscape where ZF cannot, so math also follows the razor. In the same manner, people want to work in IST/SPOT have to gain something ZFC cannot provide by introducing additional predicates such as std()...

@NotThatGuy, I agree with you that we don't just "guess" concerning foundational systems. What both user tenebris and I were referring to were "educated guesses" (with regard to both natural science and mathematics). You can't "prove" that CH (for example) should be part of the foundations of mathematics.

@MikhailKatz "Educated" in "educated guesses" seems to be doing a lot of heavy lifting (and that word is not included in your question).

"Guesses" were not included in the original version of my question, either. I was merely responding to the comment by user tenebris, who claimed that in math, unlike natural science, there are no guesses: only proofs. In reference to natural science, he was clearly using "guess" in the sense of "educated guess". I think you may have misunderstood the discussion between user tenebris and myself. @NotThatGuy
